# Linux resource monitoring per user

Tags: linux, resources, users, monitoring

I am looking for a daemon that logs, the amount of resource, utilized by every user. For every user, I would like to record the cpu-time and memory used over the lifetime of his/her processes. If possible the amount of time the process spent in different states `[R, D, S]`.

This is something in the line of the `sadc` family of tools, but I do not think it logs per user data. Could someone point me to a tool which does what I want ? This seems to be too common a task not to have a standard tool around for. So wanted to check before writing something quick and dirty that surely will not be as well thought out as an existing tool.

A similar question was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800032/finding-users-resource-utilization-in-ubuntu-linux What I am looking for is a tool rather how to do it programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might want process accounting.  Does [accton](http://linux.die.net/man/8/accton) look like what you need?

Comment: I don't know what HN is, so maybe or maybe not?  :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to turn on auditing; [See the auditd manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd)

Comment: I skimmed the documentation. Unless I have missed it, it seems it essentially logs the syscalls, the command-line, and metadata about file-IO. So it seems too low level to obtain % CPU and memory usage per user easily. I was looking more in the lines of something that logs at regular intervals the fields of top or ps.